# Unable to connect to AWS slave via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure a master-slave configuration using EC2 plugin in jenkins. After configuring the EC2 plugin, jenkins launches the slave successfully and I can even ssh into that slave. But when I look into Node logs in jenkins, I see that jenkins could not connect to slave. Here is what I'm seeing:

```
This node is offline because Jenkins failed to launch the slave agent   on it. See log for more details
INFO: Authenticating as ubuntu
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:00 PM null
INFO: Connecting to ip-10-226-254-52.ec2.internal on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:10 PM null
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:10 PM null
INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:15 PM null
INFO: Connecting to ip-10-226-254-52.ec2.internal on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:25 PM null
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
Jan 31, 2017 6:29:25 PM null
INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins
java.lang.NullPointerException
at hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.bootstrap(EC2UnixLauncher.java:309)
at hudson.plugins.ec2.ssh.EC2UnixLauncher.launch(EC2UnixLauncher.java:131)
at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:122)
at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:253)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked through online but couldn't help much. If any of you are familiar with this kind of error, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you specify the SSH key the jenkins user/process should use to connect?

Comment: @MichaelJ - Yes, I specified the key which I used to ssh from command line. Here is the sample console jenkins output 
`INFO: Launching instance: i-04f2269ce08edf96d
Feb 01, 2017 3:13:41 AM null
INFO: bootstrap()
Feb 01, 2017 3:13:41 AM null
INFO: Getting keypair...
Feb 01, 2017 3:13:41 AM null
INFO: Using key: fst-load-demo`

Comment: I'm also seeing jenkins trying to connect to slave instance continously
`INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
Feb 01, 2017 4:59:58 AM null
INFO: Connecting to 10.226.254.15 on port 22, with timeout 10000.
Feb 01, 2017 5:00:08 AM null
INFO: Failed to connect via ssh: The kexTimeout (10000 ms) expired.
Feb 01, 2017 5:00:08 AM null
INFO: Waiting for SSH to come up. Sleeping 5.
Feb 01, 2017 5:00:13 AM null
INFO: Connecting to 10.226.254.15 on port 22, with timeout 10000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess I've figured out myself. The security groups which I specified for the slave to use did not have SSH port(22) is not opened on the master's security group. After opening up SSH port I'm able to connect to slave node 
Note: I'm using same security groups for both master and slave

```
INFO: Connected via SSH.
Feb 02, 2017 4:29:59 PM null
INFO: connect fresh as root
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you still getting the same error, have to increase the sleep time: 30000

Ref: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-30284?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true

[image]